# List of all games names?

Tags: legal, game-industry

Is there any list of game names anywhere, so i can choose a name for my game and avoid (legal) conflicts with other games as much as possible?

Comment: You should also make sure you have a list of every character in every game, and every identifiable name for a game mechanic. You know, just in case.

Comment: Instead of indie, it's hipster game development. I need a name you've probably never even heard of.

Comment: There's only popplers and zigglers left.

Comment: This question has inspired me to write BIOS-Hawk. I'm not sure what the game is about yet but the name is sure to get it lots of attention. :-)

Comment: What's with all the sarcastic comments?  Do we really need to make fun of the guy's question?

Comment: tolo is means _fool_ in portugese [google translate](http://translate.google.com/#pt|en|tolo%0A).  Other than that the basic question is good.  How to safely pick a game name w.r.t. mind share, legal, etc.

Comment: Choose a name. If you can't find it on google then you're probably safe. The worst case scenario is that you will be contacted by the name owner, who will request that you change it. In that case, you change it slightly.

Comment: If you can register the domain name, it's good to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's complete but I guess you can complete it yourself if you want/need:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_video_games

Looks like there are TONS of pages *__*

For your licence problem, **a google search might be more useful**.

Also, from comments :

I think the only thing you can do to make sure you got a licence not registered is to register it. The laws of different countries and other things makes it hard to check if you have legal rights on a licence you're creating a name for. If you can't find anything on google, check again, check variants. Then if you don't find, maybe try a legal move. They will tell you if it's already taken. Or they should.

Contact a lawyer for details relative to your country laws and international laws.

Comment: +1 There is a list on which you can look up any name and see if a game exists for it and its name is Google.

Comment: @Jonathan, i was about to say i tried google but didnt, since i assume people already know i googled... i found nothing, but it doesnt mean the game doesnt exist with copyrighted name etc.

Comment: @Jonathan, also, the google search isnt going to help me if there exists a game with SIMILAR name than mine is. I want to make as unique name as possible...

Comment: @Klaim, is there some way of getting the complete list of that page without clicking thousands of links manually? (i could write a script but erm, hoping for easier way)

Comment: @Tollo: It probably _does_ mean it doesn't exist. I think you're too concerned about your name. You will probably never find the perfect absolutely incomparably unique one.

Comment: If you want a unique name I recommend a random string generator sampling from all human-language Unicode code pages.

Comment: You must also beware of using company names, if the company has anything to do with games, web, IT etc.
Basically you can't use a name that could confuse as to which company it belongs to. (i.e. you can't call your game Microsoft...)

Comment: I think the only think you can do to make sure you got a licence not registered is to register it. The laws of different countries and other things makes it hard to check if you have legal rights on a licence you're creating a name for.
If you can't find anything on google, check again, check variants. Then if you don't find, maybe try a legal move. They will tell you if it's already taken. Or they should.

Comment: yeah so there is no easy way ok case closed

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google to fast-discard some names, but if you are doing something seriously and professional I really encourage you to pay some legal advocates/experts to do that. There exists many registry for products and brand names, and all this stuff is too much complex to be managed by someone that is not an expert.

If you are starting a game I also suggest you to take a PROJECT name and leave the decision of the final PRODUCT game to a more advanced stage.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much easier way around this: go onto Google, or your favourite search engine, and search for `<yourgamenamehere> game`. If nothing comes up, it either a) does not exist, or b)is too obscure to worry about - it could be a small open source project that was abandoned for example.

Comment: as i said in my another comment, what if the name is SIMILAR to one already existing name, i cant be sure i will find those on google.

Comment: @Tollo You aren't going to have problems with similar names. If you're really that worried, a few extra searches for similar names won't hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Using a longer name with more elements in it should open your options.  For example (and I have no idea if these are real game titles because I just pulled them out of my *ahem!!  Moving right along...*):

- Potential conflict:  **Wizard Boxing**
- More likely available:  **Wizards of *the Kingdom of Norr* Boxing Championships**

Although it isn't a definitive way to check, "Googling" your game name ideas can help to prevent the majority of conflicts.  Reserving a matching internet domain name will usually do the trick though (especially for computer games).

**An important note about using Google to check names:**  If your game name includes multiple words, enclose it "*within quotations marks*" to instruct Google to handle your phrase as a single keyword.  This will save you a lot of time because fewer (if any) results, that are also more relevant, will be returned.

(***Study exercise:**  Try using http://www.Google.com/ to search for both the game names I suggested above, or something similar of your own creation, and try it with and without enclosing "quotation marks."  You'll be running four queries in total.*)

Comment: +1 for amazingly epicness in naming games... Wizards of the Kingdom of Norr Boxing Championships!

Comment: @3nixios:  Thanks!  Here's a long one based on your name (which I turned into the name of a planet; I hope you like it):  **"Planet crusaders: The secret treasures in the mountains of Nixios 3"**

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Mobygames](http://www.mobygames.com/), they're trying to build a comprehensive index of all games.

Comment: That's an interesting web site.  I particularly like seeing all the screen shots of Commodore 64 and other versions of various games all in one organized place.  They seem to be making a really good effort.

Comment: Yes they are! Please note it's a Wikipedia-like effort (although with more verification), so all contributions help too.

Comment: Contributions from the community will be useful for anyone who releases a new game.  Perhaps this web site ( http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ) could benefit from having a "resources for marketing your new game" section (this should probably be moved to meta though) that includes links to such web sites.